# ACF google map not working

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, google-maps

I tried to add google map field in ACF, but when I try to edit or add new article it show the map for sec and then diable it and wrtie:

> Oops! Something went wrong. This page didn't load Google Maps
>   correctly. See the JavaScript console for technical details.

What can be the problem? How can I fix it...

Answer (score 1):

Google is now requiring a API key for the maps.

[Getting Started With Google Maps APIs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start)

Comment: Hey, thanks for comment, I registered to google maps and get api key. where should I placed it??

Comment: I know that the Latest ACF has a function for your google Api key

Comment: Tried to search for too long and none of what I found wasn't fix the problem.... Can you help? :\

Comment: [link](https://maps-generator.com/) Just need to know your API Key:)